# SSH doesnt exit from command line

Tags: bash, unix, shell, ssh, exit

I ssh to another server and run a shell script like this `nohup ./script.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Then type exit to exit from the server. However it just hangs. The server is Solaris.

How can I exit properly without hanging??

Thanks.

Comment: The script is simply several thousands curl command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that this script is a long running one. In this case you need to detach the process from the terminal that you wish to close when you terminate your ssh session.

Actually you already done most of the work by reassigning both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`, however you didn't do that for `stdin`.

I used the test case of:

```
ssh localhost
nohup sleep 10m &> /dev/null &
^D 
# hangs
```

While

```
ssh localhost
nohup sleep 10m &> /dev/null < /dev/null &
^D 
# exits
```

I second the recommendation to use the excellent `gnu screen`, that will do this service for you, among others.

Oh, and have you considered running the script directly and not within a shell? I.e.:

```
ssh user@host script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to leave a command running remotely after you close your SSH link, I strongly recommend you use `screen` and learn to detach the screen.  That's much better than leaving background processes around; it also lets you reconnect and see what the process is up to.

Since you haven't provided us with `script.sh`, I don't think we can know for sure why the command is hanging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command  :

```
~.
```

This command close the ssh session.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh -c ./script.sh &
```